# How to create a spring bean from an enum singleton's factory method

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to springify the example code here

http://xeiam.com/xchange_examplecode.jsp

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Demonstrate the public market data service
    // Use the factory to get the version 2 MtGox exchange API using default settings
    Exchange mtGoxExchange = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(MtGoxExchange.class.getName());

    // Interested in the public market data feed (no authentication)
    PollingMarketDataService marketDataService = mtGoxExchange.getPollingMarketDataService();
```

Basically I'm looking to inject the PollingMarketDataService or the Exchange as a spring bean.

However the ExchangeFactory above is an enum, and when I tried this:

```
<beans:bean id="exchangeFactory" class="com.xeiam.xchange.ExchangeFactory" factory-method="valueOf">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="INSTANCE"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mtGoxExchange" factory-bean="exchangeFactory" factory-method="createExchange">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="com.xeiam.xchange.mtgox.v2.MtGoxExchange"/>
</beans:bean>
```

ExchangeFactory is null.

Answer (score 5):

This ought to work:

```
<util:constant id="exchangeFactory" static-field="com.xeiam.xchange.ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE" />

<bean id="mtGoxExchange" factory-bean="exchangeFactory" factory-method="createExchange">
    <constructor-arg value="com.xeiam.xchange.mtgox.v2.MtGoxExchange" />
</bean>
```

Give it a shot.